# NuGet package manager does nothing- VS 2022?

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2022, nuget-package-explorer

From within VS 2022 I navigate to **<Tools><NuGet Package Manager><Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...>**

Then I select **<Manage NuGet Packages for Solution...>** but nothing happens. There is no error and no dialog is displayed. I mean, literally, absolutely nothing happens.

Has anyone seen this / know how to fix this?

Comment: try updating your VS 2022 and then restart your pc, i just tried it on my windows PC and it works alright

Comment: If what Veronica said doesn't work, try right clicking on your solution item in solution explorer and select "Manage nuget packages for solution" instead of using the menu at the top.  If still nothing, try repairing Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I can see the Nuget Package Manager now.

Upon exiting VS 2022, the IDE prompted me . .
 - (Do you want to save your changes?)  I had been clicking (No) 
 - This time clicked (Yes) 
- The IDE pointed out the (.sln file) asking to overwrite the existing 
- I clicked (Yes) - then, 
 
**After saving the new .sln file I am now able to see the UI for Nuget Package Manager**

Comment: Hi, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider adding an answer and changing its status to Answered. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 3):

If you are in "folder view" you supposed to switch to solution view than see "Manager Nuget Packages"

[image]

[image]